# About the sum of the digits of $k^{105}$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I read [here](http://www.math.niu.edu/~rusin/known-math/96/smallnums) that

> We cannot find an integer $k>2$ such that the sum of the digits of $k^{105}$ is $k$.

Does anyone know a proof of this?

Comment: There is such an integer $k$ for every power up to 104, according to that link, for anyone reading.

Comment: The most striking thing about 105 is its prime factorization $3\times 5\times 7$ which is probably relevant...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A dumb-but-working approach could look like this:

- $k^{105}$ has $1+\lfloor\log_{10} k^{105}\rfloor=1+\lfloor 105\log_{10} k\rfloor$ digits.
- A number with $n$ digits has digit sum between $1$ and $9n$.
- Thus, the maximum possible digit sum of $k^{105}$ is $9(1+\lfloor 105\log_{10}k\rfloor)$.
- This quantity is smaller than $k$ for $k\geq 3330$.
- This reduced the problem to a finite one, which can be easily finished by a computer.

Comment: Good answer! I thought it has to do with the fact that the coefficients of $\Phi_{125}$, the $125^{th}$ cyclotomic polynomial, are not all equal to $0,\pm1$. Now I see that it's just a coincidence. Maybe an example of the [Strong Law of Small Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_Law_of_Small_Numbers).